# Hibernate criteria.setFetchMode(property, mode) is not working for child property in an entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class defined;

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "atg", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "code"))
public class ATG{

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "companyid")
    Manufacturer manufacturer;
..
}
```

When I try to fetch ATG entities with Manufacturer, I set like;

```
criteria.setFetchMode("manufacturer", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

And that is working. Means I get Manufacturer details.

I have Manufacturer class defined as;

```
@Entity
public class Manufacturer{

@OneToMany( mappedBy="manufacturer")
private List<Site> sites;

}
```

I want to fetch site object too. So, I did like,

```
criteria.setFetchMode("manufacturer.sites", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

But this is not working. That is, I could not get Site list.

How should I use FetchMode.Join in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put createAlias() in your criteria. See sample

```
criteria.createAlias("manufacturer.sites","site",CriteriaSPecification.LEFT_JOIN);

criteria.setFetchMode("site", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

Comment: No it is not working. Looks it could not Fetch a List

Comment: I posted this in hibernate forum https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1043773. I believe both are related